# What is the equivalent of `View.isSelected` in Compose

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, android-jetpack-compose, android-uiautomator

I want to use the selected state of a `Composable` from the Appium Inspector and inside automated tests with selenium.

With a classic XML `View` I can simply use the `isSelected` property.
But I didn't manage to find the equivalent in Compose. I tried setting the `selected` attribute inside the `semantics` modifier, but to no avail.
When I try the `contentDescription`, `testTag` or `text` attributes, it works. But not with `selected`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find this kind of functionality for jetpack compose. What you can do is to implement custom state for it. Whenever a use clicks the composable then we can set `isSelected` state to `true` and then can access it anywhere in the code. You can use the following sample code:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { isSelected = !isSelected }
            //... other parameters
    ) {
        //... child composables
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. The `selected` state is still unchanged in Appium Inspector. It remains at _false_.

Comment: @neige-i It will work for user interaction and also when user clicks twice then it will again change to `false` so keep that in my because the button is toggling. So if you want it selected irrespective of clicks then you can do `selected = true` in the `clickable` lambda.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. Setting the `clickable` modifier does not do anyhting. Even if I set `.clickable { isSelected = true }`, the `selected` attribute in Appium Inspector stays at _false_. It never changes.

Comment: @neige-i I understood you concern but my solution will work for only user interactions that's what I am saying and Appium Inspector is doing it with its own way that's why not working with it.